# Azure Service Bus sporadic MessageLockLostException

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Every once in a while (1 in thousands of messages) I am getting a MessageLockLostException when trying to complete a message.

I have a queue defined with lock duration set to 30s:

[image]

In code I create a listener with the following options:

```
        var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(exceptionReceivedHandler)
        {
            MaxConcurrentCalls = 10,
            AutoComplete = false,
            MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180)
        };

        var queueClient = ResolveQueueClientByQueueConfigName(queueConfigName);

        _logger.Info($"Listening on queue {queueClient.ServiceBusConnection.Endpoint}{queueClient.QueueName}");
        queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(MyMessageHandler, messageHandlerOptions);
```

And in MyMessageHandler I complete the message after successful processing:

```
    private static async Task CompleteAsync(IReceiverClient queueClient, string lockToken)
    {
        await queueClient.CompleteAsync(lockToken);
    }

    private async Task MyMessageHandler(Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Processing omitted
        await CompleteAsync(queueClient, message.SystemProperties.LockToken);        
    }
```

Like I said, this works fine for most of the messages, but once in a while I get the following:

```
2020-03-27 10:31:01,004 [64] INFO Received message: MessageId:7da4f7ec-9e27-4951-83f5-7f29d8fc93a8
2020-03-27 10:31:01,005 [64] INFO Entity Framework Core "3.1.0" initialized '"SmsDataContext"' using 
provider '"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"' with options: "None"
2020-03-27 10:31:01,087 [109] INFO Sending message to smssender, CorrelationId: 7da4f7ec-9e27-4951-83f5-7f29d8fc93a8, label: SmsSender
2020-03-27 10:31:05,205 [158] INFO Completing message '7da4f7ec-9e27-4951-83f5-7f29d8fc93a8'
2020-03-27 10:31:05,206 [158] ERROR Message handler encountered an exception 
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock 
expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different 
receiver instance.
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.DisposeMessagesAsync(IEnumerable`1 lockTokens, 
Outcome outcome)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(Func`1 operation, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.MessageReceiver.CompleteAsync(IEnumerable`1 lockTokens)
at Bcp.AzureServiceBusHelper.ServiceBusClientHelper.CompleteAsync(String queueName, Message message)
at Bcp.Sms.Validator.ServiceHost.HostedService.ProcessMessagesAsync(Message validatorMessage, 
CancellationToken token) in ***
at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageReceivePump.MessageDispatchTask(Message message). Context: 
Endpoint= prdhybrid.servicebus.windows.net; Entity Path: smsrequestvalidation; Executing Action: 
UserCallback
2020-03-27 10:31:30,949 [109] INFO Received message: MessageId:7da4f7ec-9e27-4951-83f5-7f29d8fc93a8
```

So in this case the lock was taken at 10:31:01 and the message complete failed 4 seconds later at 10:31:05, well within the 30 second lock duration.

The last log line indicates the message was retried after 30 seconds at 10:31:30 which tells me that the lock should have been valid at 10:31:05.

Could it be that the lock contained in message.SystemProperties.LockToken is corrupted?
Also, could this be due to a short network interruption? I would imagine the LockToken stays valid in this case.

This application is written in .net core 3.1 using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 4.1.2

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The lock token was not corrupted. If it was, the message as a whole would not be valid. The issue is with message could be caused by the prefetch. Check if prefetch is defined and and if so, lower its value. Lock lease timer starts ticking from the moment the client receives the message. With prefetching the client keeps the message in a “wait” state while timer is running. When the message gets to the processing callback, by the time it’s done the lock duration could have been up even with lock renewal.

Another option to validate is a clock skew.

Also, lock renewal is **not** a guaranteed operation. It’s a client-side operation that can fail. If you know your processing can take up to 3 minutes, having lock duration for that value is better.

Comment: Hello Sean, Thank you for the response.
I didn't enable prefetch. Also it seems that the timestamp in the log for the first processing attempt doesn't show any delay (message is retried exactly 30s later)
I don't use a lock renewal since it is not necessary. At the time of message complete attempt the lock still seems to be in effect.(no other workers pick up the messsage)

Comment: If everything I've described is not the case _and_ other consumers don't pick it up, have you tried to use a different entity?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with different entity. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Different queue. To rule out it's a specific entity issue. Also, I'd try Azure support. This feels very odd. If you have a repro, perhaps share a link.